# BigQuery unnest multiple params

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to unnest multiple param keys `event_date`, `page_location`,`page_title`,`user_pseudo_id`. Two of them, `page_location` and `page_title` I need to unnest and show them separately. The code below just randomly shows either the location or title value, I need them in a separate row

```
SELECT
 event_date, value.string_value, user_pseudo_id, 
FROM
  ` mydata.events20220909*`, 
    unnest(event_params)
WHERE
key = "page_title" OR key = "page_location"
```

Comment: Please provide a sample and expected data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to unnest all the event_params, with the following query, you can put any parameter in a separate column

```
select
  event_date,
  user_pseudo_id, 
  (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'page_location') as page_location,
  (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'page_title') as page_title
from `mydata.events_20220909*`
```